# How to run Octane Sever as a Daemon on Linux mint?

Tags: linux, octane-render-engine

I just installed Blender 2.81 Octane Edition and Octane Server on my Linux Mint 19, but i was unable to run the Octane server. I read the installation manual on the otoy website, on which it said that you need to run server as a Daemon, and i don`t no how its done i am new to linux environment, so please help.

Answer (score 3):

Bit of a late reply but to my understanding a daemon is just a service that runs in the background.

(This answer is based on my experience in Ubuntu)

After youve installed Octane Server and Octane Blender. Just navigate to usr/local/OctaneServer.

Double click on the OctaneServer file.

While this doesn't seem to initially do anything(Giving the impression it failed),if you boot Octane Blender and proceed to change your render engine to Octane it should ask for your Otoy login details which means the server is working.

Quick tip. Inside Preferences/Addons/OctaneEngine make sure to tick "Deactivate License on Exit" this ensures that you don't encounter any unsavoury license bugs(Assuming you shut down Blender properly).